# The equation $X^{n} + Y^{n} = Z^{n}$ , where $ n \geq 3$ is a natural number, has no solutions at all where $X,Y,Z$ are intergers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> The equation $X^{n}
>  + Y^{n}
>  = Z^{n}$
>    , where $n
>   \geq
>  3$
>     is a natural number, has no solutions at all where $X,Y,Z$
>     are integers.

*My solution*:

False. Because if we let $X=0
 ,Y=0$,
 then $0^{3}+0^{3}=0^{3}$
 . Thus there is a solution for the equation $X^{n}
 + Y^{n}
 = Z^{n}$,
  where $X,Y,Z$
  are integers.

Can anyone please give feedback on my answer and state whether it is correct on not.

Comment: YOU ARE CORRECT.

Comment: Hi new user. WELCOME! YOU MIGHT FIND [THIS MATHJAX TUTORIAL](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) HELPFUL IN FUTURE. ALSO, please don't use all-caps; there's no need to shout.

Comment: It is not clear whether $n$ is given or is a variable. I would lean to given. Then your counterexample should use $0^n+0^n=0^n$, or $1^n+0^n=1^n$.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct. Disproof by counterexample is valid.

For a bit stronger and correct variation of this, see [Fermat's Last theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem).

Comment: Yes it's just a *little* difficult;-)